# avoid NULL count mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this select:

```
select 'fv' prefix, c.user, MAX(f.data) as data, c.user, count(c.user) as logs
from favorites f inner join
     cadastro c
     ON f.user = c.id
where f.fv = '1' and c.user <> f.user and f.data > now()
```

If I have no result to show, mysql shows this:

```
prefix - user - data - user - logs
fv NULL NULL NULL 0
```

I don't want to show when there is no results. What is wrong? is the count(c.user)? how can I avoid count to count 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An aggregation query with no `group by` *always* returns one row.  One simple method is to add an aggregation:

```
select 'fv' as prefix, c.user, MAX(f.data) as data, c.user, count(c.user) as logs
from favorites f inner join
     cadastro c
     ON f.user = c.id
where f.fv = '1' and c.user <> f.user and f.data > now()
group by f.fv;
```

If there are no matches, this will not return any rows.